# Error: Actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: constructor

I am getting the following error:
"constructor Square in class Square cannot be applied to given types;
required: double,double
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

I can't find any place I'm missing a double, so I'm confused as to why this isn't happy.  Could anyone direct me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

```
class Square {

    private double Height;
    private double Width;
    private double SurfaceArea;

    Square(double sqHeight, double sqWidth) {
       this.Height = sqHeight;
       this.Width = sqWidth;
    }

        // Get square/cube height
        double getHeight() {
            return Height;
        }

        // Get square/cube width
        double getWidth(){
            return Width;
        }

        // Computer surface area
        double computeSurfaceArea(){
            SurfaceArea = Width * Height;
            return SurfaceArea;
        }


         }
```

```
class Cube extends Square {

    private double Height;
    private double Width;
    private double Depth;
    private double SurfaceArea;

    **// Error occurs here**
    Cube(double cuHeight, double cuWidth, double cuDepth) {
       this.Height = cuHeight;
       this.Width = cuWidth;
       this.Depth = cuDepth;
    }

        double getDepth() {
            return Depth;
        }

    @Override
        double computeSurfaceArea(){
            SurfaceArea = (2 * Height * Width) + 
                          (2 * Width * Depth) + 
                          (2 * Depth * Height);
            return SurfaceArea;
        } }
```

Comment: Error occurs at Cube constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the Square constructor with three arguments.

When calling Cube constructor, it will implicitly call the base constructor with the same number of arguments, in your case, it tries to find a Square constructor which accepts three double parameters.

Need to specify that you are calling the base class with two double parameters: in your case, height and width.

```
Cube(double cuHeight, double cuWidth, double cuDepth) {
   super(cuHeight, cuWidth);
   this.Height = cuHeight;
   this.Width = cuWidth;
   this.Depth = cuDepth;
}
```

Comment: Completely misunderstood the super command until now, thank you good sir, you taught me more than you know.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use inside your cube constructor:

```
    super(cuHeight, cuWidth);
```

to call the Square constructor.

Comment: You're answer whilst correct, needs to include more detail to explain why this fixes the problem. The accepted answer does this well. See [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.